# Creating instances of classes in python ??

Tags: python, qt, class

How do i  pass variables from one python module`(1st module)` to another`(2nd module)` which contains a main module and two `Qdialog` which appears when the buttons are pressed in the `2nd module`

How can i send these values from `1st module` to the `Qdialog` in the `2nd module`

I am dealing with multiple modules and data needs to updated here and there and totally confused with Inheritance/ Creating instances of classes and Modules

```
# mainwindow.py(1st module)

from 2nd_module import window2, dialog1, dialog2
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.win2 =window2()
        self.dia1 =dialog1()

        if 1:
           self.win2.bar()
           # pass data 
           self.dia1.some_function(data)
```

.

```
# 2nd_module.py
from mainwindow import mainwindow
class dialog1 (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)           


    def update(self):
        w = window2()            
        #do something
        w.self.ma.foo() 
.
.
class dialog2 (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
.
.
class window2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window2, self).__init__()
        self.update_request = 0  # initilizing the variable here 
        self.ma = mainwindow()

        self.connect(dialog1_bttn, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.open_dialog1 )

    def open_dialog1(self): #this is how i create the instance of dialog box
        self.open1 =dialog1()
        self.open1.show


    def foo(self): # this updates the request value from 2 dialog boxes
       #do something
       self.update_request = 1

    def bar(self): # this is called from 1st module to check if there are any update requests  
       if self.update_request ==1:
       #do something
```

My struggles

so here when i call `foo()` from dialog1 it works fine and updates the value to 1. But now when i call `bar()` from 1st module the value `self.update_request` turns to be 0  all the time

my `mainwindow(1st module)` runs all the background tasks like exchanging data from serial port,etc.  and i need to send that data to the `dialog1` in `2nd_module` to update the values

Can anyone please advise me on how to create proper instances of `Qt Dialogs, windows` and to  pass `data/variables/list` from one class to another ..thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have two `QtGui.QMainWindow`? Do you actually need two windows on the screen ?

Comment: @Mel i have a main application window  which has 4 buttons to open 4 other windows ans each sub window has 2-3 dialog boxes .. and everything opens in a new window